# How to group data, with restrictions on group size in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Given a data frame, I can group the rows under a stated property, count them to know the size of the group and assign them uniquely with an id number. But what I really need is to do this process so that the group sizes are restricted under the following three conditions:

1. If size modulo 3 = 0, then split into smaller groups all of size 3,
2. If size modulo 3 = 1, then split into smaller groups of size 3 and two groups of size 2.
3. If size modulo 3 = 2, then split into smaller groups of size 3 and one of size 2

Hence if size is 4 then create two groups, both of size 2; whereas when size is 5, then split into two groups of size 3 and 2.

I have created the following minimal example.

This is the starting data. Typically, it would not be ordered and could have more columns:

```
   structure(
     list(property = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G")), 
     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
     row.names = c(NA, -28L), 
     .Names = "property"
     )
```

The desired output would be:

```
structure(
  list(property = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G"), 
  id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12)), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -28L), 
  .Names = c("property", "id")
  )
```

The order of the groups is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first create a function that will create groups of equal numbers according to your requirement. Basically, it will always create groups of three equal numbers and then cut off those numbers that are too much at the end. In the special case the last group has length one, the last but one element is replaced by the last one in order to satisfy your condition 2:

```
create_grp_idx <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  m <- n %/% 3 + 1
  idx <- rep(1:m, each = 3)[1:n]
  if (n %% 3 == 1 && n > 1) idx[n-1] <- idx[n]
  return (idx)
}
```

Now I use `dplyr` to group the data by `property` and then apply `create_grp_idx()` to each group, thus creating the index `n`. I then use `interaction()` to get a factor from each combination of `property` and the newly created index `n`. Since you use numbers in your example, I convert the factor to numeric and finally remove the column with the index `n`.

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(data, property) %>%
  mutate(n = create_grp_idx(property)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(id = as.numeric(interaction(property, n))) %>%
  select(-n)
## Source: local data frame [28 x 2]
## 
##    property    id
##       (chr) (dbl)
## 1         A     1
## 2         B     2
## 3         B     2
## 4         C     3
## 5         C     3
## 6         C     3
## 7         D     4
## 8         D     4
## 9         D    11
## 10        D    11
## ..      ...   ...
```

This does not give exactly the example output you gave, but since you said that the order of the groups is irrelevant, I assume that this is the result that you want.

Comment: It doesn't work when size modulo 3 = 1, it should create two groups of size 2 but it creates groups of size 3 and one group of size 1

Comment: Now it should be better.

Comment: @Stibu Many thanks. This does indeed work. I'll need time to work out how it works, and for that I thank you for the explanation too, and I'll try and implement it to my full data set.